# Help Merging 2 PHP Functions (Wordpress)

Tags: php, function, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to merge two separate PHP functions into one that I can use in my Wordpress theme. I'm using Wordpress functions to get the post meta of the key "_videoembed" which is then trimmed from a YouTube URL down to the YouTube video ID. I'll include both the earlier functions & how I use them and then the one I'm working on. All help is appreciated very much!
-Matt

**Previous Method**

*In theme*

```
<?php 
  $vidurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videoembed", true );
  $youtube_id = getYouTubeIdFromURL($vidurl);
  $finalid = trim($youtube_id);
  echo $finalid;
?>
```

*In functions.php*

```
function getYouTubeIdFromURL($url)
{
$url_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($url_string, $args);
return isset($args['v']) ? $args['v'] : false;
}
```

**Below is an example of how I'm trying to merge the two:**

*In theme*

```
<?php getvidID(); ?>
```

*In functions.php*

```
function getvidID() 
{
  $vidurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videoembed", true );
  $url_string = parse_url($vidurl, PHP_URL_QUERY);
  parse_str($vidurl_string, $args);
  return isset($args['v']) ? $args['v'] : false;
  echo $vidurl;
}
```

As you can see, the older method I used was quite bulky, and I'm trying to streamline things so that my files are easier to work with and so that there are less PHP functions.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the functional units smaller, instead of creating a larger single function.

[Splitting a large function](http://books.google.ca/books?id=1MsETFPD3I0C&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=extract%20method%20fowler&source=bl&ots=pLM4q1VHfa&sig=Rr94t46v5PoSWOPmDlN7pzZDfHs&hl=en&ei=t256TqmfA--GsALt483bAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=extract%20method%20fowler&f=false) into smaller functional units is a known refactoring pattern called **extract method**.

Merging small functions is pretty much the opposite of refactoring, which is aimed at keeping code clean, easier to follow and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Function usage:

```
<?php get_vid_id($post->ID); ?>
```

Function itself:

```
function get_vid_id($id) 
{
  $vidurl = get_post_meta($id, "_videoembed", true );
  $url_string = parse_url($vidurl, PHP_URL_QUERY);
  parse_str($vidurl_string, $args);
  return isset($args['v']) ? $args['v'] : false;
  echo $vidurl;
}
```

But I'd recommend using less functions. Keeps your code clean. Maybe create classes?

Comment: How would I create classes? I don't know that much PHP :/

Comment: Read through [these](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). When you do `$post->ID`, `$post` is a class.

Comment: More accurately, `$post` is an object, which is an instance of a class.

Comment: You could make it even more confusing ;)